# Binding not works on DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a window which has a usercontrol in it . This usercontrol's **RequestObject** property bound to **SearchArgumentObject** property  of ViewModel of the window.

*This is listing from my window class*

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding SearchArgumentObject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <guiLib:RegCardSearchForm x:Name="SearchParametrsUC" Grid.Row="1" RequestObject="{Binding .,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

In  Usercontrol class I created dependency property:

*This is listing from my userControl class*

```
    public static DependencyProperty RequestObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RequestObject", typeof(RegistrationCardSearch), typeof(RegCardSearchForm));

    public RegistrationCardSearch RequestObject
    {
        get
        {
            return (RegistrationCardSearch)GetValue(RequestObjectProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(RequestObjectProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

On the level of the usecontrol everything works fine and RequestOject property changed.

But in my window class I can't see modification of **SearchArgumentObject** property which was made in  usercontrol.

How can I get modefied property value? I think answer to this question is very trivial but I can't find solution.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the DataContext on the Grid isn't doing anything but breaking the two-way linking of your properties. Skip the extra step and bind the VM property to the control property that you want to pick up changes from instead:

```
<Grid>
    <guiLib:RegCardSearchForm x:Name="SearchParametrsUC" Grid.Row="1"
           RequestObject="{Binding SearchArgumentObject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: i am already do that. It didn't work. That why i use additional step :(

Comment: Your additional step made things worse. Have you verified that your ViewModel is being used as the DataContext for the Window? You should also make sure you aren't setting the DataContext for your UC internally in its XAML or code-behind. I would suggest using Snoop to examine your DataContexts at runtime.

Comment: DataContext set properly. For example when i replace binding with this <TextBlock Text="{Binding SearchArgumentObject}"/> he call Get accessor of the SearchArgumentObject property, but with usercontrol and my property debugger don't enter to the get accesssor of SearchArgumentObject property

Comment: Have you looked at the DataContext of your UC? A common error is doing something like DataContext = this; in the UC code which overrides the inherited DataContext and can break external bindings.

Answer (score 0):

The code for your Window class is setting the `DataContext` of the `Grid` to a property obtained from a binding to a property on another object's `DataContext` further up the tree. Do you have the Window's `DataContext` set elsewhere?

Let's say that the object which is supplying the `SearchArgumentObject` is named `SearchWindowViewModel`. In the code-behind of the Window, you would have the following code (in the constructor, for example):

```
DataContext = new SearchWindowViewModel();
```

Now, all the properties that `SearchWindowViewModel` exposes are available to the Window. To bind the `SearchWindowViewModel.SearchArgumentObject` to the UserControl's `RequestObject` property, you would have the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <guiLib:RegCardSearchForm x:Name=SearchParametersUC Grid.Row=1 
          RequestObject={Binding SearchArgumentObject />
</Grid>
```

If you don't want to set the Window's `DataContext`, you can set the Grid's `DataContext` using the same type of code as I used above, and the binding in the XAML would remain the same.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am already use this sort of binding. It didn't work thats why I get binding from Grid. But it is very strange. {Binding} works normal on userControl but {Binding SearchArgumentObject} not works. I check DataContext everything is normal. Problem in usercontrol binding